# Access NSWindow from another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nib

I have read all the docs I can get my hands on and google'd everything I can, however, I am misunderstanding a fundamental aspect of either object-oriented programming, Cocoa, or both. I have a window that is declared in MyDelegate.h:

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *dataWindow;
```

And is synthesized in MyDelegate.m:

```
@synthesize dataWindow = _dataWindow;
```

How do I access this window from other classes? For example, I want to use a separate class for a drawer the will have `_datawindow` as its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it through you `MyDelegate` class.

```
MyDelegate *myDelegate = ...;
//MyDelegate *delegate = (MyDelegate*)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSWindow *window = myDelegate.dataWindow;
```

Don't forget to import MyDelegate header to your class

Comment: Can you point me to the Apple documentation for this case? I either do not understand your answer or something is not working for me correctly. You say I can access it through the "MyDelegate" class, but I want to access the window in the MyDelegate class from another class... does that make sense?